# PL/SQL optimize searching a date in varchar

Tags: regex, string, oracle, date, plsql

I have a table, that contains date field (let it be `date s_date`) and description field (`varchar2(n) desc`). What I need is to write a script (or a single query, if possible), that will parse the `desc` field and if it contains a valid oracle date, then it will cut this date and update the `s_date`, if it is `null`.

But there are one more condition - there are must be *exactly one* occurence of a date in the `desc`. If there are 0 or >1 - nothing should be updated.

By the time I came up with this pretty ugly solution using regular expressions:

```
----------------------------------------------

create or replace function to_date_single( p_date_str in varchar2 )
    return date
is
    l_date date;
    pRegEx varchar(150);
    pResStr varchar(150); 
begin
    pRegEx := '((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\d\d)((.|\n|\t|\s)*((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\d\d))?';
    pResStr := regexp_substr(p_date_str, pRegEx);
    if not (length(pResStr) = 10)
    then return null;
    end if;
    l_date := to_date(pResStr, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
    return l_date;
exception
    when others then return null;
end to_date_single;

----------------------------------------------

update myTable t
set t.s_date = to_date_single(t.desc)
where t.s_date is null;

----------------------------------------------
```

But it's working extremely slow (more than a second for each record and i need to update about 30000 records). Is it possible to optimize the function somehow? Maybe it is the way to do the thing without regexp? Any other ideas?

Any advice is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

OK, maybe it'll be useful for someone. The following regular expression performs check for valid date (DD.MM.YYYY) taking into account the number of days in a month, including the check for leap year:

```
(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[13578]|1[02])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\.(0[13456789]|1[012])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\.02\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\.02\.((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))
```

I used it with the query, suggested by @David (see accepted answer), but I've tried `select` instead of `update` (so it's 1 regexp less per row, because we don't do `regexp_substr`) just for "benchmarking" purpose.

Numbers probably won't tell much here, cause it all depends on hardware, software and specific DB design, but it took about 2 minutes to select 36K records for me. Update will be slower, but I think It'll still be a reasonable time.

Comment: Could you give some examples of "valid oracle dates" a lot of people won't be familiar with what that would be (including me).

Comment: I'm using format "DD.MM.YYYY"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor it along the lines of a single update query.

Use two regexp_instr() calls in the where clause to find rows for which a first occurrence of the match occurs and a second occurrence does not, and regexp_substr() to pull the matching characters for the update.

```
update my_table
set    my_date = to_date(regexp_subtr(desc,...),...)
where  regexp_instr(desc,pattern,1,1) > 0 and
       regexp_instr(desc,pattern,1,2) = 0
```

You might get even better performance with:

```
update my_table
set    my_date = to_date(regexp_subtr(desc,...),...)
where  case regexp_instr(desc,pattern,1,1)
         when 0 then 'N'
         else case regexp_instr(desc,pattern,1,2)
           when 0 then 'Y'
           else 'N'
         end
       end = 'Y'
```

... as it only evaluates the second regexp if the first is non-zero. The first query might also do that but the optimiser might choose to evaluate the second predicate first because it is an equality condition, under the assumption that it's more selective.

Or reordering the Case expression might be better -- it's a trade-off that's difficult to judge and probably very dependent on the data.

Comment: Works pretty fast, thanks! :) Much better than my monstrous function.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no way to improve this task. Actually, in order to achieve what you want it should get even slower.
Your regular expression matches text like `31.02.2013`, `31.04.2013` outside the range of the month. If you put year in the game, 
it gets even worse. `29.02.2012` is valid, but `29.02.2013` is not. 
That's why you have to test if the result is a valid date.
Since there isn't a *full* regular expression for that, you would have to do it by PLSQL really.

In your `to_date_single` function you return null when a invalid date is found.
But that doesn't mean there won't be other valid dates forward on the text.
So you have to keep trying until you either find two valid dates or hit the end of the text:

```
create or replace function fn_to_date(p_date_str in varchar2) return date is
    l_date date;
    pRegEx varchar(150);
    pResStr varchar(150);
    vn_findings number;
    vn_loop number;
begin
    vn_findings := 0;
    vn_loop := 1;
    pRegEx := '((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\d\d)';
    loop
        pResStr := regexp_substr(p_date_str, pRegEx, 1, vn_loop);
        if pResStr is null then exit; end if;
        begin
           l_date := to_date(pResStr, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
           vn_findings := vn_findings + 1;

           -- your crazy requirement :)
           if vn_findings = 2 then
              return null;
           end if;
        exception when others then
          null;
         end;
         -- you have to keep trying :)
         vn_loop := vn_loop + 1;
    end  loop;
    return l_date;
end;
```

Some tests:

```
select fn_to_date('xxxx29.02.2012xxxxx')            c1 --ok
     , fn_to_date('xxxx29.02.2012xxx29.02.2013xxx') c2 --ok, 2nd is invalid
     , fn_to_date('xxxx29.02.2012xxx29.02.2016xxx') c2 --null, both are valid    
from dual
```

As you are going to have to do try and error anyway one idea would be to use a simpler regular expression.
Something like `\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d\d\d` would suffice. That would depend on your data, of course.
Using @David's idea you could filter the ammount of rows to apply your `to_date_single` function (because it's slow), 
but regular expressions alone won't do what you want:

```
update my_table
set    my_date = fn_to_date( )
where  regexp_instr(desc,patern,1,1) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think of "...that doesn't mean there won't be other valid dates forward on the text". Maybe it's actually better to filter out records with the fast query and then apply the slow function to what's left.

Comment: Btw, while my regex doesn't check for leap years and days count in a month, I actually saw much more complicated examples, that do the trick. The question is - how fast(slow) would they work? :)

Comment: Good question. Post them up so we can run some tests. Might be of help for someone.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. :)